# Combine @media queries with javascript to change dynamically css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I am using following code to change thead css if someone scrolls down the page

```
$(document).ready(function()
{       

    $("#results").scroll(function () 
    {               
    var top = $("#results").scrollTop();
        if (top > 25)
            {

             $("thead").css({ 'position':'fixed', 'bottom':'120px', 'width':'95%', 'margin':'2.5%'});
                    }
       }
}
```

I want to use media queries to alter css depending on screen size. For instance the "thead" to be:

```
$("@media all and(max-width: 1980px)").{("thead").css({ 'visibility':'hidden' })};
```

The html code is:

```
...
<table id="demoTable">
    <thead>
       <tr id="stayontop">
        <th> sth </th>
        <th> sth </th>
        <th> sth </th>
        <th> sth </th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
...
```

My problem is that media query is not working...

Comment: http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/jquery-and-css-media-queries.. Refer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want thead tag disappears when sreen size is under a particular witdth you colud use media queries in your css file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
<title></title>
<style>
@media  screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
thead {visibility:hidden; }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="demoTable">
    <thead>
       <tr id="stayontop">
        <th> sth </th>
        <th> sth </th>
        <th> sth </th>
        <th> sth </th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case thead disappears on 1024 screen width
If you want you could use a jQuery solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
        $("thead").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }   
})
</script>
```

in this case I suggest you watch this page could be useful http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing this in jQuery, there's no need to use a media query. You can just use `$(window).width()` and `$(window).resize()`:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1980) {
        $("thead").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
});
```

What you're trying to do is select the media query, which as far as I know isn't possible.